# Calling external method from asynctask and updating ProgressDialog with data of this external method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a general question:

Is it possible to update a ProgressDialog Message with data coming from a method, that is called by an AsyncTask

```
doInBackground(Void... arg0)
```

Purpose:
The method is generating and **returning a file**. Depending on the amount of data, this may last more or less time. I would like to inform the user about the progress, telling the current page number of the generating file (page number is a value within the external method).

any suggestions how to access the value and showing it in the ProgressDialog?

I tried already:
declaring page value **public and static** and access it from the

```
onProgressUpdate(
```

with the code below the page value is returned its initial value, however its not updating any idea to obtain the updated value?:

```
    public class prepareFile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(
                R.string.CalcGatheringInformation)+"\n"+Filehandler.pages+"  -  "+values);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        publishProgress(String.valueOf(Filehandler.pages));
        prepareFiles();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this link: A very simple example

http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/an-example-of-how-to-run-a-background-task-and-report-progress-in-the-status-bar-using-asynctask-on-android/

Answer (score 1):

`onProgressUpdate` is called after `publishProgress` and you do that only once, before you even start preparing file with `prepareFiles` - that's why it is not changing later and shows initial value.

I believe you should do something along

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    while(!allPagesPrepared()){
        publishProgress(String.valueOf(Filehandler.pages));
        preparePage();
    }

    return null;
}
```

or divide `prepareFiles` job in some other way and call `publishProgress` every few steps of your loading algorithm.